# How to prevent clicking on a checkbox's label from stealing focus

Tags: javascript, html

The default behavior on Mac OS X is that clicking checkboxes and buttons doesn't steal focus from other controls that have focus (for example, a textbox). I want to implement this on the web.

I can get it working for buttons and checkboxes themselves but not for checkbox labels.

Take this jsbin as an example: 
http://jsbin.com/kopateluze/1/edit?html,console,output

Here is a screenshot of the form:

[image: Screenshot of http://jsbin.com/kopateluze/1/edit?html,console,output]

If you first focus the textbox and then click the button, you can use `event.preventDefault()` on `mousedown` to prevent the textbox from losing focus. That works nicely. And if you first focus the textbox and then click the checkbox, the same thing works.

But if you first focus the textbox and then click the checkbox's `label` text, it doesn't work; the textbox loses focus.

Is there a way to prevent clicking on a checkbox `label` from stealing focus from other controls?

Pure JavaScript, please, but feel free to link to the source code for solutions implemented in libraries.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Preventing the default upon mousedown (or click or whatever) will effectively make the elements unresponsive. What exactly is the interaction pattern you're trying to effect?

Comment: What OS and browser are you using?

Comment: *Note* For Windows Chrome checking the check-box does not lose focus, but clicking the label does. A `<label>` does not have any default action, clicking anywhere on the document will make the textbox lose focus.

Comment: Also I recommend that you should place your JavaScript not inline with your HTML, doing so is considered bad practice for the most part. Generally you want to separate it into `.js` files or `<script>`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, you're on to something: clicking the checkbox itself achieves what I'm looking for; it's just the label that's the problem. I'll update the question with this info.

Comment: @Pointy, I'm looking to prevent the element from receiving focus, not from being clickable. This method works fine for <button> elements. They don't receive focus on mousedown and clicks still work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Okay, here's what I was able to figure out, a little over two years after the fact.

## Preventing buttons from stealing focus

First, let's talk about the example that motivated this question. When a text field has focus, I'd like to prevent clicking buttons from stealing focus. I still want any button click handlers to be called, I just don't want focus to move.

To do that, we just need to know that buttons receive focus on `mousedown`, so preventing that is as simple as using `event.preventDefault()`:

```html
<input placeholder="First focus me" type="text" />

<br/>

<button
  onmousedown="event.preventDefault()"
  onclick="console.log('button:click')">
    Then click me
</button>
```

Notice that clicking the button triggers click handlers but never causes the button to receive focus. Also note that buttons can still receive focus via pressing `Tab`, so this doesn't harm keyboard access.

## Preventing checkboxes from stealing focus

It turns out, as long as you use a naked checkbox that has no label, this same technique works perfectly.

```html
<input placeholder="First focus me" type="text" />

<br/>

<input
  type="checkbox"
  onmousedown="event.preventDefault()"
  onclick="console.log('checkbox:click')"
/>
⇐ Then click the checkbox
```

But this does have accessibility problems because the text describing the checkbox isn't associated with it and the checkbox click target is just the checkbox itself, not the text that goes with it. The solution here is to add a `label` element, but this is where the problems start.

## The problem when a checkbox has a label

```html
<input placeholder="First focus me" type="text">

<br/>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox"
    onmousedown="event.preventDefault()"
    onclick="console.log('checkbox:click')"
  />
  Then click me
</label>
```

This successfully prevents the checkbox from stealing focus if you click on the checkbox. However, if you click on the text next to the checkbox, focus is stolen from the textbox.

## The fix for when a checkbox has a label

The key is in knowing how `label` elements interact with their associated `input` elements. The `label` element's `click` handler actually gets called twice: once where `event.target` is the `label` element, and once where it is the checkbox.

Therefore, the general fix is to:

1. Call `event.preventDefault()` on `mousedown` of both the label and the checkbox.
2. In the label click handler, which gets executed twice, call `.click()` on the associated control (the checkbox element), but only when the `event.target` is equal to the `label` element.

```html
<input placeholder="First focus me" type="text" />

<br/>

<label for="checkbox"
  onmousedown="event.preventDefault()"
  onclick="
    console.log('label:click');
    if (this === event.target) {
      console.log('label === event.target');
      console.log('label:click preventDefault()');
      // prevent focus and click
      event.preventDefault();
      // call click on the labeled control
      this.control && this.control.click();
    }
  ">
  <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"
    onmousedown="event.preventDefault()"
    onclick="
      console.log('checkbox:click', `checked = ${this.checked}`);
    "
  />
  Then click me
</label>
```